# Why is emphatic "Yes, I know THAT" okay, but not "Yes, I know IT"?

Tags: personal-pronouns, stress, emphasis, it-its-itself

In the context of [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/308187/is-it-necessary-to-use-it-as-an-object-yes-i-know-it-but-yes-i-know) asking about using pronoun "it" as an object, it struck me that whereas it's perfectly natural to place heavy stress for emphasis on the "demonstrative determiner" in...

> 1: *Yes, I know **that**, but not the other thing*
> ...and we can do the same with a *personal* pronoun such as...
> 2: *Yes, I know **him**, but not his wife*

...it seems to be impossible to idiomatically stress whatever kind of pronoun we call "it" in...

> 3: *Yes, I know **it**, but [caveat]*

Is there some simple principle involved here? Or is it "just one of those things"?

Comment: Interesting question. We have “this or that”, “him or her”, but what goes with “it”? In your examples, the emphasis seems to me to need something to contrast.

Comment: @ColleenV: I think the restrictions on stressing **it** may have something to do with the fact that it's not very "particular". Which may or may not be connected to the fact that we can't normally place possessive **its** at the end of an utterance (whether heavily stressed or not). So *You can pat her head, but not **his*** is fine, but we can't include that kind of stress in *This is a cat. You can pat your dog's head, but not **its***.

Comment: I have the impression that "Yes, I know it" would have been idiomatic a few centuries ago when today we would say either "I know" or "I know that".

Comment: @KateBunting: It may be that the *unstressed* form was more common centuries ago, but I find it hard to believe there was ever a time where the *stressed, emphatic* version was ever idiomatic. But that's not so easy for the likes of me to research, given we've no audio records, and the writers of old rarely attempted to convey spoken emphasis in a written form anyway (besides which they often almost randomly capitalised virtually all nouns even if that wasn't intended to imply emphasis).

Comment: (But looking at fev's more recently posted answer, maybe I shouldn't have been so sceptical / dismissive in that last comment! :)

Comment: ***I know (it)*** idiom: used to express agreement - *This place is such a mess." "I know it.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/I%20know%20%28it%29

Comment: @user66974: To repeat what I already said - that's not a "stressed, emphatic" use of the pronoun.

Comment: You can to this while pointing your finger, first at one thing then another:  "Yes, I know *it*, but not *it*."

Comment: I disagree that it can't be stressed. Any word in any utterance can be stressed in English: *I* know it. //I *know* it.//I know *it*. And it will add to meaning or lessen its blow, as it were. "stress" on words in English is a speaker's choice....not something in the dictionary.  You can prolong the sound of it, thereby stressing it.

Comment: How about this example of stressing "it"... "You spend too much time fixing up your car. Sometimes I think you love **it** more than you love **me**!"

Comment: @ColleenV: Not bad! That's actually a more natural "unlikely context for unlikely utterance" than the one in Andy Bonner's answer! Unquestionably the usage does *tend* to sound odd with heavily stressed ***it*** - but equally unquestionably, if you can come up with a good enough context, it's obviously not remotely "syntactically invalid".

Comment: (But I think if it's rephrased to put ***it*** at the *end* of the utterance, that just piles on the "non-idiomatic agony": *...Sometimes I don't think you love **me** as much as you love **it**!* sounds significantly more awkward to me than your version.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think your last example would sound a bit awkward regardless of stress, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wonder if the awkwardness when “it” is at the end of the sentence is simply because there are too many other words (and pronouns) between it and what it refers to. Also, the negation adds more awkward, although “You sold the car!? I’m glad you love **me** more than you loved **it**.” is still a bit weird.

Comment: "I thought you hated that film." "No, it's the sequel I hate. I love **it**." Plausible?

Comment: @RosieF I feel like one of the problems with that (which comes up with a lot of these examples) is that "it" by all rights should refer to the sequel at that point: "It's the sequel I hate. I despise it." So you're relying on emphasis to also change the meaning of "it". On the other hand, if we reorder to "No, I love it. It's the sequel I hate." then it's more natural to emphasize "love" to contrast with "hated".

Answer (score 24):

Aside from the fascinating history of "h" enunciation, I think the primary reasons that "it" seems less common as a candidate for a contextual stress that discriminates one pronoun from another is more practical than linguistic. As you suggest yourself, "it's not very 'particular.'" *This* and *that* are inherently suited to compare and contrast, but "it" simply identifies. I'm not sure I agree with your underlying perception, either; I think it's just that we find ourselves less often in a position to compare an "it" to an other, but it's not inconceivable.

> How do you feel about Smith and his book?
> Oh, I like *him* well enough, but I can't abide *it*.

But when comparing two "its," perhaps we seldom perform GEdgar's proposed pantomime of pointing to "*it*, not *it*," because *this* and *that* would be so much handier.

Comment: There's a lot of interesting stuff in fev's excellent answer above, but when the chips are down I think your "not inconceivable" example nails it for me. Demonstrative pronouns like ***this*** and ***that*** are naturally suited to most "compare and contrast" contexts where we want to lay heavy stress on one or both referents. It's just that suitable contexts for treating ***it*** the same way are few and far between. Whatever - I've upvoted both these answers, but unless anything else turns up in the next day or two, I'd have to say yours addressed *my* concerns more succinctly and precisely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually tried to formulate a contrived example for "*it*, not *it*," relying on having to clarify an earlier sentence that had used "it," but couldn't fabricate something remotely plausible!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps the closest might be a situation of temporary loss of articulacy, as in the immortal words from *The Princess Bride*: "Move the thing! And... the other thing!" E.g. "Move... it!" "Move what, the tiller?" "No, not *it*, you know—*it*!" But obviously, it's a stretch.

Comment: Indeed. That Princess Bride example looks a bit too much like an artificial "use / mention" context, so it doesn't really hit the spot anyway. But even though your *Smith = **him**, his book = **it*** version is *slightly* "odd", it's easily enough to convince me that "suitable context" is at least as relevant as any syntactic or semantic considerations here.

Answer (score 15):

The word "it" usually isn't the subject of emphasis in the sentences in which it is used. However, it *is* possible to come up with situations where "it" is actually the word emphasized, even in common, modern speech:

###### When "this" or "that" are already used

"That's IT! You solved the mystery."

"This is IT! The chance we were waiting for!"

###### When "it" is specifically highlighted to point out a mistake

"Yuck, it's trying to eat me." "Excuse me, IT happens to be my baby boy, and he's trying to suck your finger."

Comment: When "it" is a euphemism, "Did you and your boyfriend do it?" "Did we do what?" "You know... IT."

Comment: @user3067860 "nope, in our bed we only do THAT." (this is a joke)

Answer (score 14):

Intriguing question. Looking into ***it*** I found some interesting facts. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(pronoun)) says:

> Old English had a single third-person pronoun ***hit*** and was used for both people and objects (inanimate or abstract). In the 12th century, it started to separate and appear without an *h*.  The ***hit*** form continued well into the 16th century In Modern English but had disappeared before the 17th in formal written English. Genitive ***its*** appeared in the later 16th century and had taken over by the middle of the 17th, by which time ***it*** had its modern form.

The following sentence is interesting

> "Hit" remains in some dialects ***in stressed positions only***; some dialects also use "it", not "its", as a possessive.

So that implies that there WERE cases of stressed HIT in the past.

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=it) confirms this saying

> In some American vernacular dialects, speakers may pronounce *it* as *hit* ***in stressed positions***, *especially at the beginning of a sentence*, as in
>
> - Hit's cold out here!
>
> This pronunciation is called a relic dialect feature because it represents the retention of an older English form. In fact, ***hit*** is the original form of the third person singular neuter pronoun and thus can be traced to the beginnings of the Old English period (c. 449-1100). Early in the history of English, speakers began to drop the *h* from *hit*, ***particularly in unaccented positions,*** as in
>
> - I saw *it* yesterday.
>
> Gradually, *h* also ***came to be lost in accented positions***, although ***hit*** persisted in socially prestigious speech well into the Elizabethan period. Some relatively isolated dialects in Great Britain and the United States have retained *h*, since linguistic innovations such as the dropping of *h* are often slow to reach isolated areas. But even in such places, *h* tends to be retained ***only in accented words***. Thus, we might hear
>
> - ***Hit***'s the one I want
>
> side by side with
>
> - I took it back to the store.
>
> Nowadays, ***hit*** is fading even in the most isolated dialect communities and occurs primarily among older speakers. This loss of ***h*** reflects a longstanding tendency among speakers of English to omit *h*'s in unaccented words, particularly pronouns, such as ***'er*** and ***'im*** for ***her*** and ***him***, as in
>
> - I told 'er to meet me outside.
>
> This kind of h-loss is widespread in casual speech today, even though it is not reflected in spelling.

Now I know that this is very linked with pronunciation, but English does stress words, including pronouns, through intonation or change of pitch:

> Stressing personal pronouns often emphasizes that one person or persons is being contrasted with another. ***A change in pitch often accompanies the pronoun that has been brought into focus through stress.*** When this happens, the overall rhythm and intonation of the sentence changes, sometimes significantly. ([source](https://pronuncian.com/reducing-pronouns-he-him-her-and-them))

So, the fact that modern *it* lost the *h*, might indicate that it simply ceased being used in stressed positions in the process. ***Why*** that is would definitely be interesting to know... Could it be related to our inherent understanding of the superiority of persons over inanimate objects?

**Addition**:  The way demonstratives behave with phrasal verbs (sorry for those who do not agree with this term), may shed some light:

> Q: If I start a plant indoors and then move it outside, I can say either “*I will harden off the plant*” or “*I will harden the plant off.*” ***But if I use a pronoun, I can only say*** *“I will harden it off,”* not *“I will harden off it.”* What’s going on here?
>
> A: When this kind of phrasal verb has an object, and the object is a noun, the noun can go either in the middle of the phrase (“harden the seedlings off”) or at the end (“harden off the seedlings”).
>
> But if the object is a personal pronoun, it has to go in the middle (“*harden them off*”), not at the end (“*harden off them*”).
>
> (We should add that ***while personal pronouns can’t go at the end, demonstrative pronouns can: “this,” “that,” “these,” “those.”*** Nobody blinks when we say things like *“Did you harden off those?”* or *“Please hand out these.”*) ([grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/06/phrasal-verbs.html))

Conclusion? Yes, demonstrative pronouns are obviously stronger candidates for stressed uses than any personal pronoun, let alone ***it***.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that somewhere we have a question asking why the corresponding genitive, *its*, is fairly uncommon as a stressed pronoun, at least compared with *mine, thine, his, hers, yours, theirs*.

Comment: @tchrist ... which is also FFingers' intuition expressed in the comments.

Comment: I would never say: harden off a plant. That sounds completely unidiomatic. The idiom has to be: harden it **up**. The entire issue of pronunciation is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Lambie It's a gardener-specific idiom, but [it is one](https://www.rhs.org.uk/prevention-protection/hardening-off-tender-plants).

Comment: @AndyBonner: Quite. [Ngrams not found: *harden **up** the seedlings*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harden+off+the+seedlings%2Charden+up+the+seedlings&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Charden%20off%20the%20seedlings%3B%2Cc0), but there are plenty of written instances of *harden **off** the seedlings*. Maybe it's an "artefact", but [***toughen up***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toughen+them+up%2Charden+them+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) has recently become *far* more common than ***harden up***.

Comment: As a native speaker, experimenting, "I can't stand **it**" doesn't really work but "I can't stand **hit**" does. Something to do with the initial."H" being suitable for emphasis in terms of tone and forcefulness, where an initial "I" isn't.  So I'd tend to agree with this answer although without any theoretical basis, just familiarity with the language.

Comment: @Stilez: Unless you're a native speaker of *medieval* English, I don't see how you can say *I can't stand **hit*** "works" - but you could certainly say *I don't mind being insulted, but I can't stand to be **hit**!* with heavy stress on that aspirated final word. As a sort of Cockney speaker myself, I find it hard to imagine  ***not*** aspirating ***hit*** in that exact context, even though I routinely do so in other contexts. A more likely example: *I quite like **her**, but I can't stand **him*** - where I defy even the most die-hard Cockney to defend emphatic *...can't stand **'im**!*

Comment: @Lambie It's a specialized usage, it may be regional as well, but it's definitely harden _off_ and never harden _up_ when used in this context. Collins Dictionary has it ( https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/harden-off ) and you can find it defined in, e.g., gardening magazines, gardening sections of news papers, plant vendors, agricultural extensions of universities or governments... https://extension.psu.edu/hardening-transplants

Comment: @Stilez I doubt the _i_ is the problem, although I do see the allure of the idea. I have no issue emphasizing other short words starting with _i_. Would you have trouble with *She's **ill***? Or even with the use of the same word but in a different context like *Huh? You object to the word **it**?*. For me, at least, the latter example works fine while I would have the same problem as FFingers with *The color?  You object to **it**?*.

Comment: @terdon - not comparable. Forgive my horrible lack of technical knowhow but as spoken: "she's ill" (almost always pronounced "she zill" - the initial I gets merged into the MIDDLE of a sound) and "I know it" (NOT really pronounced "Know wit", the initial I remains FIRST letter). How do comparable phrases work, such as "I saw it/held it/remember it/touched it". And, "I know ink". Those might be revealing?

Comment: @Stilez ah yes indeed. Very fair point about how _ill_ is not really pronounced as starting with an `i`. Heh, all of this is intriguing but might deserve its own question so as not to spam the comment thread (my bad, I started it!).

Answer (score 3):

Your examples are similar in nature to passives, which sometimes may specify an agent with the preposition "by", and *sometimes may not*. The times when this is not possible are the same as the times when "it" doesn't work in your examples.

Consider for example,

> A new book on the topic is being prepared by well-known author Smeghead Johnson, who for the fourth year running has been nominated for the Best-Smelling Optician of the Year Award.

works much better than

> A new book on the topic is being prepared by me.

This latter sentence seems very strange. It is because in that locus (i.e., the nounphrase or pronoun governed by "by"), you expect something salient. Salient could mean "new information", something the phrase itself is introducing to the discussion.

As a rule, pronouns are less salient than noun phrases, because their antecedents are agreed and known. This certainly holds for "me" and "it". The only times it's possible to use these words are when we already agree on who or what they refer to.

"This", "that", "here", the interrogatives like "how", etc. are more salient than that. This is because they contrast with each other, and they point things out more. and so on. So they are less restricted in where they may be placed (they are more likely to be fronted, or uttered in isolation, etc. etc.)

Comment: I've long been familiar with [Grice's Maxims](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html), so I can easily see how "The maxim of relation" could be said to reference "salience" as an attribute at the level of complete *utterances*. But you've introduced me to the new and interesting concept of salience as an attribute of ***individual words / expressions** [as used **within** an utterance]*. Many thanks for that!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, it's the tip of the iceberg. Some languages (Greenlandic, Navajo) even have different verbal conjugations depending on if something's salient or obviative.

Comment: I knew even as I wrote the words above that I should have said *...new **to me** [and interesting to potentially **anyone**]* lol :)

Comment: @OmarL My favorite situation is languages like (I believe) Cree, in which the most salient (or "proximate") noun in an utterance is unmarked, and all other ("obviate") nouns carry mandatory grammatical marking. This allows a proximate noun, usually a person, to be introduced once and left implicit until another explicit proximate noun shows up.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is, does one need a pronoun or a determiner?

"I don't know whether you remember Woolworth's on the Strand; I used to shop there often."
"Yes, I knew it well."
----> pronoun -- *it* stands in for the proper noun *Woolworth's*

"Be careful when you go foraging -- it's easy to pick poisonous mushrooms by mistake."
"I know that."
-----> determiner -- the understood phrase *that information you shared* is reduced to *that*).

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of "content clauses".

A: “The red piece goes on top of the green piece.

B: Yes, I know that, but where does the yellow one go?”

= B: Yes, I know *that the red piece goes on top of the green piece*, but where does the yellow one go?”

*that the red piece goes on top of the green piece*, is a content clause. It tells us the content of what is known.

You will see that, in *Yes, I know that* the pronoun **that** is a short/pronoun version of a content clause.

A content clause is a noun clause and thus can be replaced with a pronoun. However, the pronoun is usually a demonstrative pronoun such that it refers back (in this case) to the last spoken statement.

Compare:
The red piece is heavy. I know **this** (i.e. that it is heavy), but you say that the yellow piece is light: you have not weighed the yellow piece so how do you know **that** (that it is light)?

However, where there is no content clause:

A: How did you know the meaning of that word?

B: I don’t know – I just knew **it**. (it = the meaning)

a simple pronoun is used.

Comment: "I know it" does not suddenly become idiomatic because the stand in is no longer a clause instead of a lone noun. "The answer is 42" / "I know the answer" | "The answer is 42" / "I know that" | "The answer is 42" / "I know it"

Answer (score 0):

It would be unusual to say "I know it" as a response to an idea or suggestion instead of "I know that" (common), "I know this" (unusual, but not as rare as "it") or even simply "I know," (also common).

This is more the reason this stands out than choosing to stress 'it,' as a native English speaker that word just 'feels' out of place in that sentence - it's not grammatically incorrect, it's just not the idiom.

In addition, there is also the fact that 'it' is rarely stressed in sentences in which it is typically used - this has to do with 'it' having a general connotation of neutrality.

"This" implies nearness, "That" implies distance, but "it" is usually selected specifically because it lacks an implication - it'd be like stressing your lack of reaction to something, which is sort of inherently awkward.

There are a few instances where one might stress "it" as an insult when referring to a person or animal - in this case the stress implies a profound lack of regard. This is considered rude or even hateful if a person is the subject, as it implies you consider them less than human, so I would strongly recommend not doing this.

Comment: Maybe "I know it" is not common, but _**I knew it!**_ certainly is.

Comment: @fev True! I think there is some concept hiding in there about conversational pronoun use, like under what conditions you get to use a given pronoun when you're the person who introduces the subject to the conversation vs. when it was someone else, but it all seems very fuzzy and I'm not aware of any formal encoding of those "rules."

Comment: @IIron Gremlin We are all splitting hairs here clearly, but I find it fascinating! It's amazing to feel the pulse of a language even if somewhat "blindly"...

Answer (score 0):

My earlier response isn't helpful bc I misunderstood the question -- sorry.

FumbleFingers, by the logic of the examples you gave, one *can* emphasize "it":

---- Do you know that couple, John and Jane? / I know **him** but not his wife (or, I know **him** but not her).
---- Do you know the store Blip and its CEO, Jane Jones? / I know **it** but not her. (That said, one can't know an inanimate object; one would say, "I know of **it** but not of her.")

I think the confusion arises bc, in the ELL question that prompted your question above, the person who asked it misused the pronoun **it** where the determiner **that** was needed:  "Yes, I know that [piece of information], but I love her regardless" -- and, one would emphasize the verb *know*, not the determiner *that*.

In addition, that ELL example consists of two disparate ideas, expressed as two independent clauses; if emphasis is wanted or needed, it would have to fall on the verb (a recast version shows this: "I *love* her, and I don't *care* about that [piece of information]"). By contrast, "I know X but not Y" is a compound predicate with two parallel objects, so the speaker would place emphasis on one object (to differentiate between the two parallel objects) rather than on the verb.