# "..., as it were, ..."

Tags: etymology, idiom-meaning

The phrase "as it were" can mean figuratively, or indicate a non-literal sense. Cambridge Dictionary defines:

> sometimes said after a figurative (= not meaning exactly what it appears to mean) or unusual expression.

My question is how the phrase comes to have this meaning, apart from what it means. The plain meaning of the phrase seems innocuous enough - as the way it is. The verb "were" suggests a subjunctive mood. How do these two elements add up to mean what they mean?

An example from Severin Shroeder's book *Wittgenstein*:

> ... the progression is not linear, but moves into two directions: not only forward, but also sideways, *as it were*, into notes on preceding remarks and notes on those notes, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sensed correctly that ***were*** is subjunctive. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as--it--were) explains that the idiom is

> a shortening of “***as if it were so***” .

Apparently,

> this idiom has been in use since Chaucer's time (he had it in his *Nun's Priest's Tale*, c. 1386).

I searched a bit and found this is correct:

> He looketh ***as it were*** a grym leoun, And on his toos he rometh up and doun. (*[Nun's Priest's Tale](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E4DXD7Sk7WcC&pg=PA258&dq=he%20looketh,%20as%20it%20were,%20as%20a%20grym%20leoun&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPvLfK1uL7AhWs_rsIHaQeDXMQ6AF6BAgLEAI)*)

It is thus clear that *as if it were so* does not mean *as it is*. *As it were*, is saying something looks like something else, but is not literally the same.

The OED says this idiom originated from an archaic form of the subjunctive mood:

> a. Introducing a supposition, expressed by the subjunctive mood: As if, as though. arch.

The same dictionary defines it as

> **As it were**: *as if it were so, if one might so put it, in some sort*: a parenthetic phrase used to indicate that a word or statement is perhaps not formally exact though practically right.

Comment: The OED has a couple of older citations than Chaucer [here](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307?redirectedFrom=as+it+were#eid38318924).

Comment: I am sure... Unfortunately, I have no access to it. Can't even open your link. But if you wish, you can edit my answer to include some of those examples, if you think it is important.

Comment: Oh. Then here is what they give for its definition: “***as it were***: (as a parenthetic phrase used to indicate that a word or statement is perhaps not formally exact though practically right) as if it were so, if one might so put it, in some sort.”

Comment: I hadn't finished writing. :) A prior citation is: “c1400  (▸?a1387)    W. Langland *Piers Plowman* (Huntington HM 137) (1873) C. ix. l. 22   Ich wolde a-saye som tyme for solas, **as hit were**.” The pronoun *it* used to pronounced with a leading *[h]* sound, and was written *hit* to reflect that. Eventually the *h*-droppers won out, and several million years after they stopped saying it that way, they actually changed the spelling.

Comment: Isn't that one year later though?

Comment: I actually answered one question looking into this _[hit](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/583742/407211)_ thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the obvious fact that *were* is subjunctive to *be*, the idiom "as it were" in this question is not trivially explained as such.

The definition of the idiom in question is given as "sometimes said after a figurative (...) or unusual expression."

A more basic phrase is *as they say*, *as we say*, or as Wiktionary has it

> Synonyms: so to speak, in a manner of speaking, in a way ([as it were](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_it_were))

Note that they distinguish two competing definitions. The difference is present already in the earlier Middle English quotations, making the origin difficult to judge.

---

@tchrist in comments submitted the following quote from the OED (“c1400 (▸?a1387) W. Langland Piers Plowman (Huntington HM 137) (1873) C. ix. l. 22"):

> Ich wolde a-saye som tyme for solas, as hit were

> ? I might save some time for "solas", as it were.

This fits the bill, inasmuch as the purpose of the word is to hint at hidden connotation: *Solas [~ of man]* "sexual intercourse" (MED, umich.edu; nota bene, not "of men") strikes me as likely. It stands to reason that "solas" is a euphemism and "of man" a later addage.

Since the idiom, *as it were*, has achieved wider popularity, it is probably not the equivalent of todays *if you know what I mean ;)* in origin. Except, when the aspect of *evidentiality* is flaunted to the point that the suggestive meaning is supposed to be self-evident, we have to reckon with the occasional misunderstanding, which is not always intentional. Similarly, one has to wonder about the negative sentiment expressed by the adverb *so-called* used to call out intentional deception.

At any rate, the expression is not subjunctive, *maybe*, although that would make sense.

---

This analysis is not immediately applicable to the contemporary quote from Chaucer (Nun's priest's tale)

> He looketh as it were a grym leoun; ...

The surface analysis with subjunctive *be* is adequate. It translates nearly one on one to the German conjunctive, *Er sah aus als wäre er ein Löwe*, the big difference being the pronouns. This implies that either the pronouns were still in flux - *(h)it* and *he* are cognates - or the phrase was already conventionalized as an adverb. Strictly speaking, it does not match the definition because the idiom does not come *after* the marked expression.

In a slightly later example, the marked clause is not obviously figurative nor is it unusual (KJB 23:22)

> God brought them out of Egypt; he hath as it were the ſtrength of an Vnicorne.

Th'is remarkable because the original Hebrew could have no unicorn as such, and the grammar differs anyway but its interpretation seems to be problematic to begin with ("כְּתֹועֲפֹ֥ת רְאֵ֖ם" *ke·to·v·'a·fot re·'em*).

In this view, KJB looks to say that *some have reported* the appropriate translation had to be "like a unicorn" in Latin and that this may seem silly to you now but you really had to be there. I won't argue with the scholarship if the metaphor is meaningful, as I'm sure the existing literary criticism is extensive.

---

What I'm driving at is this. Since *verbose, word* etc. are derived from reconstructed **werdʰh₁om*, from a reconstructed root **werh₁-* "to say, speak", that is otherwise not continued in English as far as I can see (haven't ever heard of *wray, to bewray* "to deceive"), it should be difficult to prove but we may plausibly derive the word, *as it were*, from this root, at least in part. See also *swear*. We had better ignore *very* < Latin *verus* "true" because it has no verb sense, and Latin *vero* "I tell the truth" is unknown in English. Do note that *word* "promise" is quite close to the idea: *vows* tend to be formulaic; *mottos* (or *Devise* in heraldry) tend to be popular, rhethorical devices. In particular, by-names like *the lion* have definitely become conventionalized.

The two different semantics are then simply to be explained by the different perspectives on, respectively, a foreign or familiar expression.

Potentially, it is to 1Pl. *we* what *idioma* (Italian "vernacular") is to *id* "self", cp. Greek ῐ̓́δῐος "pertaining to self", Aeol. acc. ϝέ "him", etc. This is crucial because many an idiomatic espression is contracted from a row of short words and we do see similar *w- roots pertaining to desideratives, optatives. I mean, it's certainly reductive and speakers employ reduction based on limited evidence all the time, ie. folk etymology and analogy, so the chances are quite high that different influences fall together.

---

The example in the question represents a third alternative resting on the past tense sense of *were*, I believe.

> the progression is not linear, but moves into two directions: not only forward, but also sideways, as it were, ...

Despite the present tense usual for reports, the author gives the impression of a report retracing their steps because movement metaphors are so powerful:

> ... into notes on preceding remarks and notes on those notes,

Of course it marks the choice of words as tongue-in-cheek, but the superposition of past tense and subjunctive is *distal* as it reinforces that

a) that's really what happened (past tense)

b) they have it sorted out (present tense in matrix clause)

c) it could happen again (subjunctive).

Here another comparison with German is in order. Conj. *wäre* and past tense *war* (rhotacized *waz) are not imediately related, as they say, to future tense *wird* and its paste tense *wurde* any more than *to be* relates to *was*, but they surely sound closely related for a reason. Equivently, the lexical aspect of this use of *were* is that of *become* or passive voice *develop*, noting that there is no productive past participle of *become* - it is the participle just as *were* may be the past tense of *were* - so a more creative solutions has to be devised: *it moves into two directions: not only forward, but also sideways [] into notes on preceding remarks and notes on those notes, as [events unfold]*.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it all wrong!  The correct expression is "as a *twer*".  A "twer" is an annoying animal that makes idiotic Facebook posts.

Comment: I would have thought that posting on Facebook was idiotic by definition.